# Material-UI theme remove after page refreash

Tags: javascript, reactjs

- I am facing a problem with my custom theme, whenever i refreshes my
  page my custom theme for Tabs and Button in Navbar disappears,
  sometime it doesn't even loads the Tabs and estimate button custom
  theme.

  Also in Header.js file code it says theme is not used but i am using
  it in makeStyle function. (theme is declared on line-2 of Header.js).

Following are my code File:

Header.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import theme from "./Theme";
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import {AppBar, Box, Button, Tab, Tabs, Typography, useScrollTrigger} from "@mui/material";
import {Toolbar} from "@mui/material";

import logo from '../../assets/logo.svg'

function ElevationScroll(props) {
    const { children} = props;

    const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
        disableHysteresis: true,
        threshold: 0
    });
    return React.cloneElement(children, {
        elevation: trigger ? 4 : 0,
    });
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme=> ({
    toolbarMargin: {
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
        marginBottom:"3em"
    },
    companylogo:{
        height:"7em"
    },
    tabName:{
        marginLeft:"auto",
    },
    tab:{
        ...theme.typography.tab,
        minWidth:10,
        marginLeft:"25px",
        color:"white"
    },
    estimateButton:{
        ...theme.typography.estimateButton,
        height:"45px",
        borderRadius:"25px",
        marginLeft:"25px",
        marginRight:"25px"
    },
}))

function Navbar(){
    const classes = useStyles();
    const[value,setValue]=useState(0);
    const handleChange=(e,value)=>
    {
        setValue(value);
    }
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <ElevationScroll>
                <AppBar position={"fixed"}>
                    <Toolbar disableGutters={true}>
                        <img alt="company logo" className={classes.companylogo} src={logo} />
                        <Tabs className={classes.tabName} value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
                            <Tab className={classes.tab} label={"Home"}/>
                            <Tab className={classes.tab} label={"Services"}/>
                            <Tab className={classes.tab} label={"The Revolution"}/>
                            <Tab className={classes.tab} label={"About Us"}/>
                            <Tab className={classes.tab} label={"Contact Us"}/>
                        </Tabs>
                        <Button variant={"contained"} color={"secondary"} className={classes.estimateButton}>Free Estimate</Button>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </ElevationScroll>
            <div className={classes.toolbarMargin}/>
        </React.Fragment>

    );
}
export default Navbar;
```

Theme.js File:

```
import {createTheme} from "@mui/material/styles";

const arcBlue="#0B75B9";
const arcOrange="#FFA500";
const Theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: `${arcBlue}`
        },
        secondary: {
            main: `${arcOrange}`
        }
    },
    typography: {
        tab:{
            fontFamily:"Raleway",
            fontWeight:1000,
            fontSize:"1rem",
            textTransform:"none",
            color:"white"
        },
        estimateButton:{
            fontFamily:"Raleway",
            textTransform:"none",
            fontWeight:700,
            fontSize:"1rem",
            height:"45px",
            color:"white"
        },
    }
});

export default Theme;
```

App.js File:

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/ui/header";
import {ThemeProvider} from "@mui/material/styles";
import theme from "./ui/Theme";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Navbar/>
        </ThemeProvider>

    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```